# Backbone View not refreshing when model changes

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm getting an error 'Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'' in the console. Please see fiddle.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/vineet85/AQx63/6/

```
var RefreshingView = new Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('text'));
    }
});

var m = new Backbone.Model({text: new Date().toString()});
var myView = new RefreshingView({model: m, el: 'body'});

myView.render();

setInterVal(function() {
    m.set({text: new Date().toString()});
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off, first for *"declaring"* your views and models you should leave out the new keyword, second you shouldn't be trying to *"instantiate"* the backbone.js model directly, try the following instead

```
    var RefreshingView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: 'body',

        initialize: function () {
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.model.get('text'));
        }
    });

    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        text: null
    });

    var m = new MyModel({ text: new Date().toString() });
    var myView = new RefreshingView({ model: m, el: 'body' });

myView.render();

setInterval(function () {
    m.set({ text: new Date().toString() });
}, 1000);
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQx63/10/)

Comment: (1) Instantiating `Backbone.Model` without bother to extend it first should be fine. (2) There is no `setInterVal` function. The stray `new` when extending `Backbone.View` is, AFAIK, the real problem.

Comment: I thought it wasn't considered good practice to try and use the Backbone Models directly, but I guess if you don't need any defaults etc. it doesn't hurt. (As for the setInterval I didn't catch that misspelling, I stopped as soon as I saw there was some output...). Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any non-contrived case where I'd use a non-extended `Backbone.Model` but I don't think there's anything wrong with it. I'm pretty sure I'd always `var M = Backbone.Model.extend({})` but I don't know if that's a good habit, bad habit, or best practice :)

Comment: I think it's good practice to keep an extended model instance. In any case, you're not really saving much by calling it directly anyways.